# Symfony2.5.3 Form field "entity" - Could not load type "entity"

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, formbuilder

I have this problem with SF2 when adding a form field of type "entity". This is my case:

1. I have Country entity and CountryFormType
2. I have Network entity and NetworkFormType
3. This NetworkFormType contains Country field so in my NetworkFormType.php:

   ```
   $builder->add('country', 'entity', [
       'label' => $translator->trans('global.labels.country'),
       'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Country',
       'property' => 'name',
       'choices' => $countries
   ])
   ```

I also have declared the public setters and getters in my Network entity.
By the way, I registered my form as a service:

```
mybundle.form.network:
    class: MyBundle\Form\NetworkFormType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: mybundle_form_network }
```

But it always results to:

```
Could not load type "entity"
```

Reference: [entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is weird indeed.

According to this [API documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/EntityType.html), `EntityType` class is located within `Doctrine Bridge`.

**Packagist:** https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/doctrine-bridge

Do you have it installed? Maybe you're not using full-stack Symfony?

Comment: I was not actually using Doctrine on this project since my data source comes from API. I was not also aware before that there is a REST support from Doctrine. Thanks for the hint regarding the Doctrine Bridge. Clearly it is because I didn't make use of doctrine on this project might be the reason for this issue. As for now I'll find another alternative on my current code-flow. Much thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, when using `entity`you need to provide `class` parameter ([it's marked as required in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#class))

```
$builder->add('country', 'entity', [
    'label' => $translator->trans('global.labels.country'),
    'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Country',
    'property' => 'name',
    'choices' => $countries
])
```

I allways see `data_class` used for custom types

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'      => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task'
        ));
    }

   public function getName()
   {
       return 'task'; // this is the name of your type, you can use it instead 'entity' in your add method
   }

}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: Thanks @isalgueiro. jperovic answered my problem. But this is a good hint for future reference. :)